# Understanding Windows 8 users account and remote desktop

Tags: windows-8, active-directory

I do not want to further confuse myself by asking on the difference between domain account and local account.

Just want to clarify the following behavior for local accounts.
Let's say I created 2 normal user account.  Account A and Account B.

1. How does windows prevent Account A from seeing Account B files ?

   - if UserA has store a file "example.txt" in C:\somefolder instead of C:\Users\UserA\
     will userB be able to see the "example.txt" that userA create ?
2. if UserA has install some programs at C:\Program Files,  is UserB able to use and start the same program ?

   - How does one prevent a program installed by UserA from being run by userB ?
3. if UserB is able to start the same program, does that means that there will be 2 different instance of the same program running in the background ?
4. I am logged in to the local account AccountB at PC1,  if I remote desktop to PC1 and wanted to login as AccountB,   what will actually happen? Will AccountB be logoff (and all the programs shutdown ?) and being login again remotely ?

Lastly, can any gurus point me to where can I read more about behaviours of Window accounts (local and domain),concurrency behavior, groups and policy

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Please try and ask 1 question at a time (otherwise your question will be closed at too broad).
Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does windows prevent Account A from seeing Account B files ? -
>   if User A has store a file "example.txt" in C:\somefolder instead of
>   C:\Users\User A\ will User B be able to see the "example.txt" that user A
>   create ?

Through an Access Control List (ACL), in Windows, the ACL is on the Security tab on the properties window of the file or folder.  In your specific example User A could prevent User B from accessing the folder but that isn't the default behavior.

> If User A has install some programs at C:\Program Files, is User B
>   able to use and start the same program?

Yes.  If User A was an Administrator they could even install the program for all users, which put be a shortcut to the program, on the desktop for all users that exist on the system.  Applicable to Windows XP and above.

> If User B is able to start the same program, does that means that
>   there will be 2 different instance of the same program running in the
>   background?

If both users are logged in that is indeed the case.

> I am login to the local account Account B at PC 1, if i remote desktop
>   to PC 1 and wanted to login as Account B, what will actually happen?

You will force Windows to switch the user and machine will be locked indicating another user is accessing the machine.

> Will Account B be logoff (and all the programs shutdown ?) and being
>   login again remotely?

Account B will not be logged off, Windows will just switch to the other user, and the machine will locked.

> Lastly, can any gurus point me to where can i read more about
>   behaviors of Window accounts (local and domain),concurrency behavior,
>   groups and policy

There are hundreds of books that describe security of Windows.  You should start with one of those.

Comment: thanks for the reply! for q1 - what would be the default behavior then?  q2 - can normal account install programs ? can UserA install some program  and have that program run by userB later ? q3 - can you elaborate further, what will i see on the local machine that is logged in as AccountB if i remote login as AccountB as well ?

Comment: Q1 - Test it yourself; Q2 - A non-Administrator account by default cannot install programs; Q3 I cannot elaborate further, you should test it out, a great learning opportunity.  I was very specific.  The machine will be locked, there is nothing else to add, test it yourself if you want specifics.